LoadRunner Cloud Integrated with CICD pipeline using Jenkins Post Execution Results E-mail notification code creation
Can someone please guide on the steps on Loadrunner Cloud (saas version) with Jenkins to have CICD Pipeline. Configured E-mail Notification, SMTP and Port its working need to sent post execution results through email. Please let me know how to attach file path.
I have below code need attaché post execution results through email notification
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('lrc') {
            steps {
                lrcRunTest testId: "268", projectId: '1', sendEmail: true
                lrcGenTrendingReport benchmark: 0, runsCount: 5, trtAvgThresholdImprovement: 5, trtAvgThresholdMajorRegression: 10, trtAvgThresholdMinorRegression: 5, trtPercentileThresholdImprovement: 5, trtPercentileThresholdMajorRegression: 10, trtPercentileThresholdMinorRegression: 5
            }
        }
        stage('Send_Email') {
            steps {
                mail to: "${EMAIL_RECIPIENTS}",
                subject: "CI: Project name",
                body: "Test done"
           }
        }
    } }


Hi Exports,
Can you please provide post execution results attachment file code.
